# opening a fragment from BottomSheetDialogFragment, showing beneath the BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to open a fragment from `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, it opens but behind the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. When I dismiss the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` I am able to see the fragment that I opened.
Any idea why it is happening

I am using navigation component for navigation between the fragments.

Comment: I have fixed it, I was calling BottomSheetDialogFragment.show(parentFragmetManager, tag) Instead of calling this with parentFragment manager, update this to child fragment manager like this  BottomSheetDialogFragment.show(childFragmentManager, tag).